# Show all user posts in one page but query is too slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to show the videos and pictures shared by the members in one page. The query I wrote works fine but is very slow. I don't know why this happened. That's why I need your help. You can also see the conditions I wrote in the following query.

Here is the [**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ae34b/1)

```
$morequery=""; 
if($lastpostid) { 
  $morequery=" AND P.user_post_id<'".$lastpostid."' ";
}

$GetAllPostQuery = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT 
   P.user_post_id,     
   P.user_id_fk,P.post_type,
   P.who_can_see_post,
   P.post_image_id,P.post_video_id,
   P.post_video_name, 
   U.user_name, U.user_fullname,U.influencer_status 
 FROM user_posts P 
   INNER JOIN users U 
   ON P.user_id_fk = U.user_id
 WHERE 
   U.user_status='1' AND 
   U.influencer_status = '1' AND 
   (P.who_can_see_post IN('everyone','influencer','friends')) AND 
   (P.post_type IN('image','video')) $morequery 
 ORDER BY 
    P.user_post_id 
 DESC LIMIT " .$this->perpage) or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
  //Store the result
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($GetAllPostQuery)) {
     // Store the result into array
     $data[]=$row;
   }
     if(!empty($data)) {
        // Store the result into array
        return $data;
     }
```

The Users Table Here:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:8889
-- Generation Time: Sep 10, 2019 at 11:56 AM
-- Server version: 5.7.23
-- PHP Version: 7.2.10

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_status` enum('0','1','2','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_fullname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `influencer_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--
--

-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And The User Posts Table Here:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_posts` (
  `user_post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_type` enum('text','image','link’,’video','audio','avatar','cover','gif','location','watermark','which','page','event','blog','group','product','bfaf','inf') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
  `post_created_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1524910573',
  `who_can_see_post` enum('everyone','onlyme','friends','influencer') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'everyone',
  `post_video_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_video_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_audio_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_image_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for table `user_posts`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_posts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_post_id`),
  ADD KEY `ex_posts` (`user_id_fk`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `user_posts`
--

ALTER TABLE `user_posts`
  MODIFY `user_post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 

--
-- Constraints for table `user_posts`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_posts`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ex_posts` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id_fk`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`);
```

What should I do to make the query work faster? Can you help me.

Comment: Apply index use partitioning

Comment: slowness it not the worst thing here.. You should worry more about security as your code is prone to SQL injections..

Comment: How many records are we talking about? How long does it take? Also, is it the actual query or the presentation of the results that's slow?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The results are too slow. We are talking about 800 records. But the page showing just 30 result because of the `DESC LIMIT 30`

Comment: Questions about performance should at minimal include `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` for every table involved in the question/query (this includes foreign key relation tables aswell) .. And a `EXPLAIN <query>` without that information we can't give a valid answer we can only guess..

Comment: @DeltaForce if you run the query manually and add 'EXPLAIN' at the beginning of the query this will provide you with diagnostic info which will help us.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It takes about 14 seconds.

Comment: i am pretty sure what happens here..  JOIN with ORDER BY is tricky to optimize..  ideally MySQL optimizer should acces the table first on which the ORDER BY runs then it can direclty stream the data (pipelined) the client instead of making a temporary table (which can be memory or disk based) when accessing the other table first before sending it to the client..  The more modern MySQL optimizers have this optimisation and tends to avoid creating a temporary table..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Your last comment is true but how can i do that!

Comment: *" Your last comment is true but how can i do that!"* No idea without tables structures  and or without knowing the MySQL version..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Added the CREATE TABLE and the version.

Comment: Dont see `user_status` column in your table defintion.Also even if you index the enum columns since the values repeat often it won`t help you.Put an EXPLAIN before your query,run it and edit your question with the result.

Comment: @Mihai There is not have any problem about the result. I have a slow result problem. Data is displayed too late.

Comment: I asked because you have U.user_status='1' and if user_status is INT those quotes might prevent index use.Not the case after your edit

Comment: @Mihai Thank you. I have created a sqlfiddle for better understand. I hope it will help you to help me. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ae34b/1

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle contains too few rows to reproduce the problem but these 2 indexes might help.it really depends on your data distribution.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD KEY(user_status,influencer_status);
ALTER TABLE user_posts ADD KEY(who_can_see_post,post_type);
```